# Convert with audacity from bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash, mp3, audacity

I have multiple .wav files (numbered from 1) which I want to convert them to .mp3.
audacity can do that with opening a file and exporting using it's GUI.

Is there a way that I do this with a bash command so I can do the whole job with a bash loop?

Comment: LAME can be used from the command line.
The official documentation is here: http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE

Comment: Converting .wav to .mp3 you may loose quality. To not loose quality use .flac format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the codecs installed (libavcodec52 or similar), and ffmpeg, something like this should work:

```
for i in `ls /my/wav/dir/*.wav`; do ffmpeg -i $i -acodec libmp3lame `basename $i .wav`.mp3; done
```

I always like to test crazy loops first to make sure the syntax is coming out right:

```
for i in `ls /my/wav/dir/*.wav`; do echo "ffmpeg -i $i -acodec libmp3lame `basename $i .wav`.mp3"; done
```

Comment: This works if the filenames do not contain spaces.